# Powershell can't get ipv4adress from Get-NetIPConfiguration

Tags: powershell, script

```
$NetConf = Get-NetIPConfiguration
$Adapters = Get-NetAdapter -Physical
$NetAdapterStatus = $Adapters | ForEach-Object {
    $Adapter = $PSItem
    $AdapterProfiles = $NetConf | where {$Adapter.ifIndex -eq $_.InterfaceIndex}
    $AdapterProfiles | Select-Object 
        @{n='Name';e={$Adapter.Name}},
        @{n='Status';e={$Adapter.Status}},
        @{n='MAC';e={$Adapter.LinkLayerAddress}},
        @{n='IP';e={$Adapter.IPAddress}}
    }
Write-Host $NetAdapterStatus
```

I have result: Name, Status, MAC and like that IPv4Address=Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance[]
Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's because of the way you are calling the objects, in your code and the scope that they are in.

Comment: @postanote, Thank you. It helped and works perfectly. Prishiate

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.

Comment: @postanote, if my adapter is disable, the code show result: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.Po
werShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData

Comment: It should, then you need to use conditional logic to check state (disabled), try/catch or if/then to cast those off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this information grab with say something like this.

```
Clear-Host
Get-NetAdapter | 
ForEach-Object {
        $PSitem | 
            Select-Object -Property Name, InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, Status, 
            MacAddress,  LinkSpeed,
            @{
                Name       = 'IPAddress'
                Expression = {(Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex ($PSItem).ifindex).IPv4Address}
            }
} 
# Results
<#
Name                 : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
ifIndex              : 205
Status               : Up
MacAddress           : 00-15-5D-4A-C1-BC
LinkSpeed            : 10 Gbps
IPAddress            : {$null, 172.21.159.249}
#>

Clear-Host
Get-NetAdapter | 
ForEach-Object {
        $PSitem | 
            Select-Object -Property Name, InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, Status, 
            MacAddress,  LinkSpeed,
            @{
                Name       = 'IPAddress'
                Expression = {(Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex ($PSItem).ifindex).IPv4Address}
            }
} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Name     InterfaceDescription              ifIndex Status MacAddress        LinkSpeed IPAddress              
----     --------------------              ------- ------ ----------        --------- ---------              
Ethernet Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter     205 Up     00-15-5D-4A-C1-BC 10 Gbps   {$null, 172.21.159.249}
#>
```

Or via the cmdlts you choose to use this way:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | 
ForEach {
    $NetIP = $PSItem

    Get-NetAdapter -Physical | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, InterfaceDescription, Status, MacAddress, LinkSpeed, LinkLayerAddress,
    @{
        Name       = 'IPv4Address'
        Expression = {$NetIp.IPv4Address}
    }
}
# Results
<#
Name                 : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
Status               : Up
MacAddress           : 00-15-5D-4A-CC-B2
LinkSpeed            : 10 Gbps
LinkLayerAddress     : 00-15-5D-4A-CC-B2
IPv4Address          : 172.21.151.33
#>

Get-NetIPConfiguration | 
ForEach {
    $NetIP = $PSItem

    Get-NetAdapter -Physical | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, InterfaceDescription, Status, MacAddress, LinkSpeed, LinkLayerAddress,
    @{
        Name       = 'IPv4Address'
        Expression = {$NetIp.IPv4Address}
    }
} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Name     InterfaceDescription              Status MacAddress        LinkSpeed LinkLayerAddress  IPv4Address  
----     --------------------              ------ ----------        --------- ----------------  -----------  
Ethernet Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter Up     00-15-5D-4A-CC-B2 10 Gbps   00-15-5D-4A-CC-B2 172.21.151.33
#>
```

Comment: i found what i need:
`$NetAdapterStatus = (Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Where-Object { $_.NetAdapter.Status -ne "Disconnected"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $PSitem | Select-Object -Property Name, Status, MacAddress, 
            @{
                Name       = 'IPAddress'
                Expression = {(Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex ($PSItem).ifindex).IPv4Address}
             } 
        } | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String)`

Comment: Good work, happy scripting. ;-}